# Printing a reciept on Dot matrix printer with custom paging from C#, asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Have been looking for this from past 2days couldn't sort out, finally im here.
Now starting  with the Question,
How to Print a reciept on dot matrix printer and stop after printing one reciept with out continuing to prnt complete page with white spaces from C#, iam able to print using the below JScript code, but continues to print whole page even after reciept is completed.

```
   function Print-content() {              
           var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('div2');  
           var WindowObject = window.open('', "PanelDetails"
             ,"width=1000,height=550,top=100
             ,left=150,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes
             ,status=no,resizable=no");
           WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
           WindowObject.document.close(); 
           WindowObject.focus();  
           WindowObject.open();               
           WindowObject.print();               
       }
```

But after printing half page, printer doesnt stop it proceeds and prints complete page with white spaces, well thats a usual problem seen on many sites but didn't come up with a solution, So have shifted to server side coding, using ITextSharp Dll.

Can some one please help me with complete solution for printing a reciept half Page and stop the printer after printing last line of the page, which is vertical half of the Letter Fanfold 8-1/2'' 11'' size.

for more clarity if required i will post C# code aswell, but in order not to mess i ignored the code

Thanks in advance

Here's my C# code

```
 StringReader sr;
 private void ExportDataListToPDF()
{

   using (PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument())
    {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    this.div2.RenderControl(hw);
    sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());         
    doc.DocumentName = "Hello";
    doc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;   
     PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("MyCustomSize", 216, 279);
     doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
     doc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
     psize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Custom;
    doc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = doc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height / 2;
    doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
    doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "EPSON LQ-1150II";
    doc.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
   // doc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = sw.ToString();
    doc.Print();
    }

    }

    public void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
System.Drawing.Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 12);
float linesPerPage = 0;
float yPos = 0;
int count = 0;
float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
string line = null;

// Calculate the number of lines per page.
linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
   printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

// Print each line of the file.
while (count < linesPerPage &&
   ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null))
{
    yPos = topMargin + (count *
       printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
    ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black,
       leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
    count++;
}

// If more lines exist, print another page.
if (line != null)
    ev.HasMorePages = true;
else
    ev.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

Comment: Don't think this is possible... You don't have very much control over the result when printing from a webpage. *If* your main purpose is to print several receipts on a single piece of paper maybe you could have the users select several and print them at the same time.

Comment: is it possible to print from C#, i need this DIV to be read in C# and print the out put, but now iam getting HTML tags as output, could you help me out, if thats possible i wil try with iTextsharp. papersize attibutes on it